# Is it possible to use a variable to destructure an object?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

I recently answered a question with this code as an answer:

```js
var jobs= [
  {"startDate": "5/2017", "endDate": null, "isCurrent": true, "seniority": "Senior",},
  {"startDate": "5/2013", "endDate": "5/2019", "isCurrent": false, "seniority": "Junior"}
]

// Answer
const findObject = (obj, prop, value) => obj.filter(obj => obj[prop] === value)
console.log(findObject(jobs, 'seniority', 'Senior'))
```

I tried to destructure the object in the filter like this:

```
const findObject = (obj, prop, value) => obj.filter(({[prop]}) => prop === value)
```

But ended up with this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

Is it possible to destructure an object with a variable (or in this case parameter) name?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could take a [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) and a new variable for the value with a [object property assignment pattern [YDKJS: ES6 & Beyond]](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/es6%20%26%20beyond/ch2.md#object-property-assignment-pattern).

```js
const findObject = (obj, prop, value) => obj.filter(({ [prop]: v }) => v === value)

var jobs = [{ startDate: "5/2017", endDate: null, isCurrent: true, seniority: "Senior" }, { startDate: "5/2013", endDate: "5/2019", isCurrent: false, seniority: "Junior" }];

console.log(findObject(jobs, 'seniority', 'Senior'));
```

Comment: Yes, I've seen this before. Is there no shorthand for the `[prop]: v`? I would've assumed the object would've assigned prop the value to itself? For example, if `a = 0` rather than writing `obj = { a: a }` you could just write `obj  = { a }`, I thought there would've been something similar.

Comment: it is not possible to use a computed variable, only a computed property (as part of an object) and this requires a real (known in before) one.